# Load already existing libraries to renv without downloading

Tags: r, renv

It's been i while since I have started coding with r but I'm new renv and r projects.

My problem is the following: we have many custom packages and libraries we use in our everyday work that are well written and work properly with rstudio.
I installed those packages and everything is good until now.

The problem is when I use and initiate Renv I can no longer use them. I wasn't able to find a way to call them from my standard libpath.

For example, when i execute `renv::install("data.table.customed")` it will go automatically to the CRAN although the package doesn't exist there. I tried `hydrate()` i tried `restore()` i tried everything and i always get the same result. It seems like r will try to look for downloads rather tha looking into local librairies.

So is there a way to transfer these packages from my standard lib path to my renv libraries ?

Instead of loading already installed packages, renv ell try to download them again.

Comment: from the renv vignette:  "Custom R Package Repositories
Custom and local R package repositories are supported as well. The only requirement is that these repositories are set as part of the repos R option, and that these repositories are named. For example, you might use:

repos <- c(CRAN = "https://cloud.r-project.org", WORK = "https://work.example.org")
options(repos = repos)
to tell renv to work with both the official CRAN package repository, as well as a package repository you have hosted and set up in your work environment."

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want data.table.customed to be linked,run

```
renv::hydrate(packages = 'data.table.customed',sources = '/the /path/to/your/used/library/folder')
```

or you just write library(data.table.customed) and save in file, then run

```
renv::hydrate(sources = '/the /path/to/your/used/library/folder')
```

R will detect the default dependancies and install it for you